# Sentry with SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, sentry

- We have an application on Reactjs
- We have an SSR that builds the app on webpack, renders this application and returns HTML
- Then on the client-side we hydrate the app
- So the app is run on both server and client sides.

**Problem:**

We'd like to use sentry in react, so that it can be used on both client and server sides, because an error may occur in either place

**What we've tried:**

There are 2 modules @sentry/browser and @sentry/node.
We tried to make a module that would do:

`export default isClientSide ? SentryBrowser : SentryNode`

So if it's client, then use SentryBrowser. If server - SentryNode

But @sentry/node can't be run on webpack since it can't resolve node dependencies like `fs`, `path` etc.

**Question:**
How can we use a single Sentry interface on both client and server sides for React like @sentry/nextjs works on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Our solution was to pass in an errorHandler prop to the app. When rendering on the server we'd pass in @sentry/node's captureException, and on the client we'd pass in the @sentry/browser's one. Seemed to work just fine.

```
const App = ({errorHandler}) => {
  ..
  return (<ErrorBoundary errorHandler={errorHandler}>
    ..
  </ErrorBoundary>);
```

Then on server:

```
import { captureException as serverCaptureEx } from '@sentry/node';

hydrate(..., <App errorHandler={serverCaptureEx} />)
```

and on client:

```
import { captureException as clientCaptureEx } from '@sentry/browser';

render(..., <App errorHandler={clientCaptureEx} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't.

Client-side is wrapped in special HOC, called in most cases [Error Boundary](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/components/errorboundary/). React passes up an error to the root component of the project and catches it and reports it to the URL. This is a browser, which is client's "server", can do requests on ethernet and so on.

If you run NextJS server, not `html export` (extremely important condition!), under the hood it is uses some NodeJS libraries ([Express](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js), for example). This server has nothing in common with Webpack or JS compilation and is used as middleware. [As you can see](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/#verify), it is just a wrapper upon some route or functionality.
If you got an error on server, it is reported by NodeJS, not Webpack. So the flag somewhere in React or Webpack plugins will not help you.

One more time - client and server are different environments, browser and NodeJS server. The errors are reported by servers, not bundlers. Webpack will not help you here.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it. But how do people solve it anyway? It means If my FE app is run on both server and client sides and I'm using webpack on both sides, I can only use @sentry/browser? And if an error occurs while it's rendering on the server, it won't report it (since there's now window.fetch or some other browser's methods in nodejs) In this case for the sake of sentry I need Nextjs. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry. I'm using webpack only on the server-side for sure to make a bundle (not on both sides).
But it can't build the app If I import @sentry/node somewhere, because @sentry/node has other node module dependencies, like path, fs etc.
So it's possible only to use @sentry/browser which strips you of reporting bugs during the server rendering...

Comment: You have no need to import @sentry/node anywhere, except `next.config.js` file. This is the way. You can export configuration from this file with `withSentryConfig` wrapper. And only server will know about those errors. Check the tutorial 

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#extend-nextjs-configuration

Pay attention, it's `@sentry/nextjs` library
If you have default NextJS server configurations and no `next.config.js` file, than now you should add it, because your server is getting custom :)

Comment: But I'm not using nextjs. I'm asking if I need nextjs in case I want to have sentry on SSR. But ok, thank you anyway